# Automatic float32 promotion in numexpr

Tags: python, numpy, pytables, numexpr

Consider the following NumPy array of dtype `float32`:

```
In [29]: x = numpy.arange(10, dtype=numpy.float32)
```

When I multiply it by `2` using `pytables.Expr`, I get a `float32` array back:

```
In [30]: tables.Expr('x * 2').eval().dtype
Out[30]: dtype('float32')
```

Yet when I multiply it by `2.0`, I get a `float64` array back:

```
In [31]: tables.Expr('x * 2.0').eval().dtype
Out[31]: dtype('float64')
```

Is there any way to specify the floating-point literal in the above expression in a way that would *not* cause the result to be promoted to `float64`?

More generally, I have an expression using `float32` arrays, and I want to ensure that the result is also of type `float32` (I don't mind `float64` being used for intermediate calculations, but I can't afford to store the results as `float64`). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty certain the `pytables.Expr` is based on `Numexpr`. The documentation for Numexpr notes the following about promotion in expressions:

> In operations implying a scalar and an array, the normal rules of
>   casting are used in Numexpr, in contrast with NumPy, where array types
>   takes priority. For example, if 'a' is an array of type float32 and
>   'b' is an scalar of type float64 (or Python float type, which is
>   equivalent), then 'a*b' returns a float64 in Numexpr, but a float32 in
>   NumPy (i.e. array operands take priority in determining the result
>   type). If you need to keep the result a float32, be sure you use a
>   float32 scalar too.

So that is probably what is happening. The floating point constant is responsible for promotion to 64 bit floats, and the solution is to explicitly specify floating point constants as float32.